# Flatten tuple containing numpy array to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I used `operator.attrgetter` to try to rip an array class into a numpy array by `tupleList=map(attrgetter(*inNames),inClass)` and ended up with something like this for `tupleList[0]`

`(1, array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 'f'), 1)`

I'd like to turn that into a numpy array (specifically a structured array, but I can work that out) that looks like this

`array([1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1], dtype=(('id', 'i8'), . . . .)])`

Unfortunately, `np.asArray(tupleList[0])` and `np.asAnyArray(tupleList[0])` don't work and I get

`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`

Is there a way around this?  Currently fighting my IT division to get pandas, but don't have it right now.  I assume that would that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.hstack` in order to integrate your tuple :

```
In [106]: foo = (1, np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 'f'), 1)

In [107]: np.hstack(foo)
Out[107]: array([ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.])
```

Comment: That works 1d, is there a way to do this for the whole tupleList?

Comment: @DanielForsman But your question relates to 1D and not the entire tupleList. Changing the requirements of your question after an answer has been provided is not very fair.

Comment: Understood.  In any case it seems `np.array([np.hstack(t) for t in tupleList])` works.